# Does data in Amazon S3 go on public internet when i use job glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm using AWS services to create a datapipeline
I have data stored in an Amazon S3 bucket and I plan to use the glue crawler to crawl the data under a prefix to extract the metadata and after a glue job to do ETL and save the data in another bucket.

My question is : in which network the services works and communicates each other? it is possible that the data will be moved from Amazon S3 to glue through the public internet?

is there any link to aws documentation that explain which networks AWS services uses when they transfer data between them?

Comment: In general: no. Especially when staying within a region / az traffic does not go through the public internet. Security is one reason, another is that AWS would then compete with other internet traffic. If they route it themself they can optimize the traffic and the route it takes. Even when going cross region chances are your traffic never goes through the public internet, for the exact same reasons.

Comment: Related, non-AWS study: https://konekti.us/post/what-aws-customer-should-know-about-the-aws-global-backbone/

Answer (score 0):

You need to grand explicit permission to any resource to be able access your S3 bucket.

AIM Roles. Using policy create a role and attach that role to AWS resource.

Bucket Policy is another mechanism to grant access.

By default everything is private, you need to grant access otherwise No is not accessible from the internet.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, I have defined the IAM role and related permission and the pipe is working...but I don't understand this: when glue execute the job and access the data in my s3 bucket....to access the dat it use the public internet or not?